# About the adjoint of the Bergman projection.

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, adjoint-operators, bergman-spaces

Let $D$ the unit complex disk and let $\mu$ be the Lebesgue measure on $D$. If $\nu>-1$, define $\varphi_\nu(w):=(1-|w|^2)^\nu$, define $\operatorname{d}\mu_\nu:=\varphi_\nu\operatorname{d}\mu$ and define the $\nu$-Bergman projection as: $$B_\nu :L^1(\mu_\nu)\rightarrow H(D), f\mapsto\left(z\mapsto \int_D\frac{f(w)}{(1-z\bar{w})^{2+\nu}}\operatorname{d}\mu_\nu(w)\right),$$
where $H(D)$ is the space of holomorphic functions on the disk. Following the ideas in the proof of the theorem 6, page 37 of the book Duren and Schuster - Bergman Spaces, I stumbled upon the following problem:

> *if $B_\nu$ is bounded from $L^1(\mu_\nu)$ to itself*, then:
>   $$\forall f\in L^1(\mu_\nu), \forall g\in L^\infty(D), \int_D B_\nu(f)(z)\overline{g(z)}\operatorname{d}\mu_\nu(z)=\int_D f(w)\overline{B_\nu(g)(w)}\operatorname{d}\mu_\nu(w).$$

In order to prove this assertion I tried to use Fubini's theorem, but I can't see how its hypothesis are satisfied. In particular I can't prove that:
$$\int_D\int_D|f(w)||g(z)|\frac{1}{|1-z\bar{w}|^{2+\nu}}\operatorname{d}\mu_\nu(w)\operatorname{d}\mu_\nu(z)<+\infty,$$
only from the hypothesis that $B_\nu$ is bounded.

Comment: I apologize for my previously incorrect solution. A complete (and hopefully correct) solution is below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $n \ge 1$, let $f_n(w) = f(w)1_{|w| \le 1-\frac{1}{n}}$. Then $$\int_D\int_D|f_n(w)||g(z)|\frac{1}{|1-z\bar{w}|^{2+\nu}}d\mu_\nu (w)d\mu_\nu(z) \le ||g||_\infty\int_D |f_n(w)|\int_D \frac{1}{|1-z\bar{w}|^{2+\nu}}d\mu_\nu(z)d\mu_\nu(w)$$ $$\le \int_D |f_n(w)| C_n d\mu_\nu(w) < \infty$$ where we used that $C_n := \sup_{|w| \le 1-\frac{1}{n}} \int_D \frac{1}{|1-z\bar{w}|^{2+\nu}}d\mu_\nu(z) < \infty$. Therefore, Fubini applies and $$\int_D B_\nu(f_n)(z)\overline{g(z)} d\mu_\nu(z) = \int_D f_n(w)\overline{B_\nu(g)(w)}d\mu_\nu(w)$$ for each $n \ge 1$. As $f_n \to f$ in $L^1(\mu_\nu)$ and $B_\nu$ is bounded, we have $B_\nu(f_n) \to B_\nu(f)$ in $L^1(\mu_\nu)$. Then since $g \in L^\infty$, we have $$\int_D B_\nu(f_n)(z)\overline{g(z)} d\mu_\nu(z) \to \int_D B_\nu(f)(z)\overline{g(z)}d\mu_\nu(z).$$ Therefore, we just need to show $$\int_D f_n(w)\overline{B_\nu(g)(w)}d\mu_\nu(w) \to \int_D f(w)\overline{B_\nu(g)(w)}d\mu_\nu(w).$$ However, $\int_D f(w)\overline{B_\nu(g)(w)}d\mu_\nu(w)-\int_D f_n(w)\overline{B_\nu(g)(w)}d\mu_\nu(w) = \int_{|w| > 1-\frac{1}{n}} f(w)\overline{B_\nu(g)(w)}d\mu_\nu(w)$ does go to $0$ as $n \to \infty$ since $f(w)\overline{B_\nu(g)(w)} \in L^1(\mu_\nu)$.

Comment: I just realized that I can't show how to justify that $w\mapsto f(w)\overline{B_\nu(g)(w)}\in L^1(\mu_\nu)$. This is the case if $B_\nu(g)\in\ L^\infty$ but I can't see how this follows from the assumptions I made...

Comment: @Bob so you're saying in particular that the problem statement might not be well-defined?

Comment: you are perfectly right... it should be a part of the conclusion that RHS is well defined...

Comment: @Bob yea I don't know... I don't know how to disprove, for example, that $f(w)$ and $B_v(g)(w)$ blow up like $\frac{1}{\sqrt{w-1}}$ near $w = 1$.

Comment: the problem is that in the reference in the question the authors claimed without proof that if $B_\nu$ is bounded from $L^1$ to $L^1$ then $B_\nu$ is bounded from $L^\infty$ to $L^\infty$... and i can't show how...

Comment: @Bob I think this problem shows that fact lol

Comment: I don't get it :(

Comment: If you have this duality, $\int_D B_v(f)(z)\overline{g(z)}d\mu_v(z) = \int_D f(w)\overline{B_v(g)(w)}d\mu_v(w)$ for $f\in L^1, g \in L^\infty$, then it's very easy to show that if $B_v$ is bounded from $L^1$ to $L^1$, then $B_v$ is bounded from $L^\infty$ to $L^\infty$

Comment: yes... that's why I originally asked the question... but as you noted, maybe this is not the way to prove it, since showing that RHS is well defined seems "nearly" equivalent to the fact that $B_\nu$ is bounded from $L^\infty$ to $L^\infty$

Comment: Hmm... correct me if I'm wrong, but can't you prove boundedness by proving duality for a dense subset. Like, suppose $T$ is a linear operator such that $\langle Tf,g \rangle = \langle f,Tg \rangle$ for all $g \in L^\infty$ and $f$ in some dense subset of $L^1$. And suppose that $T$ is bounded from $L^1$ to $L^1$. Then is it true that $T$ is bounded from $L^\infty$ to $L^\infty$?

Comment: If the answer is "yes", then since we know the duality holds for compactly supported $f$ (say), we can deduce $B_v$ is bounded from $L^\infty$ to $L^\infty$ and then we know the RHS is well-defined for any $f \in L^1, g \in L^\infty$.

Comment: It seems pretty much like the path you followed in your answer... problems pop up when taking the limit $\langle f_n,Tg\rangle, n\rightarrow\infty$... or at least it seems to me...

Comment: @Bob yea, I was being stupid. I guess we just have to use the specific structure of Bergman projections somehow.